# How can we wait for a result in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've been searching everywhere for info on promises or async/await, but they don't seem to work.  I need to get the current date from a query function before I can use that date in subsequent functions. This is my best guess so far:

```
    // Retrieve current session date
    var currentDate;
    async function getMaxDate() {

        fetch(url).then((data) => {
            return data.json();
        }).then((json) => {

            // This is the date used in queries
            currentDate = json[obj].max.substr(0, 10);
            console.log(currentDate);

            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(currentDate);
                }, 5000);
            });

        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error('There was an error:');
            console.log(e);
        });

    }


  async function getAllData() {
        try {
            currentDate = await getMaxDate();
            await getMarket(currentDate);
            console.log(currentDate);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
        }
    }

    // This function is called when the document is first loaded
    $(function () {
        let promise = getAllData();
    });
```

But the behavior is the same with or without the promise/async/await - currentDate is still undefined until a few seconds later.  I also tried calling this way:

```
    getAllData()
        .then(function (currentDate) {
            console.log(currentDate);
        });
```

Here currentDate is still undefined until a bit later.  For additional clarification - getMaxDate does a fetch which may be just slow enough to cause this problem.  Because later in that function, console.log(currentDate) does output the correct value.  (currentDate is defined as a global variable.)  But it's like my code is getting executed in random order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look for below: 
Working example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/4fu6as7x/27/)

```
let currentDate;
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

function getMaxDate() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fetch(url).then(data => {
      return data.json();
    }).then(json => {
      console.log('data from api', json);
      currentDate = new Date(); // here I simulate to get Date
      console.log(currentDate);
      resolve(currentDate);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('There was an error:');
      console.log(e);
      reject(error);
    });
  })

}


function getMarket(date) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve({
      market: 'US',
      date
    });
  });
}

async function getAllData() {
  try {
    let currentDate = await getMaxDate();
    console.log('getAllData', currentDate);
    return await getMarket(currentDate);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('An error occurred.');
  }
}

// This function is called when the document is first loaded
$(function () {
  getAllData().
  then(result => {
    console.log('do sth...', result);
  });
});
```

Comment: "the function you are awaiting must return a Promise".  Async functions can also return non-promise values.  They will automatically be wrapped in a resolved promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  That code still gives me the same undefined result though.  It must be that my getMaxDate function takes too long to return the data.  Maybe I will try a different approach.

Comment: Do I need a longer timeout?  Or maybe a callback approach?

Comment: The best would be to see your getMaxDate function. Without it is difficult to advise anything.

Comment: Ok, I added my getMaxDate function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it meets your needs. I have simulated fetching using fake api.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  The key was to wrap the fetch also into the promise, as you illustrated.

Answer (score 4):

Your function doesn't return anything. If you want it to return `currentDate` you must do that explicitly.

```
async function getAllData() {
    try {
        let currentDate = await getMaxDate();
        await getMarket(currentDate);
        console.log(currentDate);

        return currentDate;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
    }
}
```

The return value will be what gets assigned in either a `then` case, or an `await` one:

```
let currentDate = await getAllData();

getAllData.then(currentDate => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Adding on to this, the documentation says "A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function." - [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value). So if you ever need a catch/reject chain, rejects catch uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I added the return value, and tried your .then but currentDate is still undefined... maybe I need to use callback functions?

Comment: Are you sure the `currentDate` you're asking for is the same one you're assigning? In your code it's a local variable (via `let`) so it won't be visible externally.

Comment: currentDate is assigned as a global variable earlier.  But I tried this using currentDate2 (local) and got the same undefined result.

Comment: If it's a global, the `let` is creating a shadow variable that you assign to instead. Don't do that, remove the `let` part.

Comment: I tried without let, but got the same result.  It just refuses to wait for getMaxDate to return a value.

Comment: Remember to correctly propagate your return values, especially in promise chains. `getAllData()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks again, it turned out to be a combination of not returning a value correctly, and not wrapping everything in a Promise.